# A clarification on a GPL "interpreter clause" corner case

Tags: licensing, gpl

The GPL clearly states that in the case of interpreters, if the interpreter is linked against a derived work, and the interpreted program code reaches those bindings, then the licensing extends to it as well.

But what about a more intermediate representation? Think of it less of a "program" and more of a "save file", out of which the runtime can produce a program on the fly, which it can then execute.

Does the license obligation still extend to the save file?

Answer (score 10):

> The GPL clearly states that in the case of interpreters, if the interpreter is linked against a derived work, and the interpreted program code reaches those bindings, then the licensing extends to it as well.

No, it does not. I suspect you are referring to the [GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#InterpreterIncompat) but *the FAQ is not the GPL*; it is "just" the FSF's opinion as to some consequences of using the GPL. The FAQ certainly expresses the FSF's desires and was probably written in conjunction with some reasonably good lawyers, but it has no legal standing.

The question you need to answer is (as always) "is the representation a derived work of the GPL-covered work?", and that is a question of copyright law, independent of the GPL or any other licenses. There is no bright line here and in the long run it would be a question for a court to decide. I can certainly imagine cases both side of the line.

Comment: So if I copyright a song that contains instructions, and someone implements that sequence of instructions in a program that links against gpl code, then my song could potentially be subject to its licensing obligations?

Comment: Absolutely not. Your song is your copyright and no actions of a 3rd party can force you to release it under the GPL; what happens here is that there are two incompatible licensing conditions on the program (your "all rights reserved" copyright and the GPL conditions) - at that point the program simply cannot be distributed.

Comment: If that legal stalemate state means it cannot be legally distributed, doesn't that mean there's just as much obstruction to legally prosecuting its distribution?

Comment: No; I don't honestly see how you make that leap - if you violate any single one of the licensing conditions, the copyright holder can prosecute.

Comment: But even if copyrighted, it can still be variable under some permissive use license that is not gpl? What if the implementer is allowed use the work and ports it though the gpl code path on his volition?

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between "allowed to use the work" and "allowed to create derivative works and release them under a new license".

Comment: So I need to put it in **my** license that 3rd parties are **not** allowed to derive my work through "invasive" licensed code, and I am done with it, with any violations - entirely on the 3rd party user?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you talk to a lawyer if you're trying to draft your own license. In any case, this is definitely now off-topic for this site.

Comment: @dtech I think you're looking at this exactly backward. If you created a work (the song, in your example) and someone created a derived work (a computer program, in your example) the computer program is always subject to *your* work's license terms. Nothing the derived author *or anyone else* can do will affect *your* work's license. A song would probably be licensed under Creative Commons, not GPL.

Comment: @dtech A unique work hardly cannot be not copyrighted. Nobody is allows anything unless they have a license. As such a license only ever gives permissions with various strings attached

Comment: By **default** with absolutely no license 3rd parties are **not** allowed to derive your work except for fair-use (in the US, most countries don't have fair-use doctrine). So they can derive your work if they want to use your work to teach others about your work but not profit from it, they can do it to criticise your work (but they cannot use it simply as illustration to criticise other things that does not relate to your work), they use a tiny incidental amount of your work (eg. a video of someone using a laptop in the background of a cafe does not need permission from Microsoft) etc.